# What's the best way to get started learning how to write an extremely simple multithreaded c++ program that includes mutex and semaphore use?

Tags: c++, multithreading

What package should I use and what would a "hello world"-level program look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [C++: Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/)

Chapter 1. Introduction is freely available in that website, and IIRC that includes a multi-threaded "Hello, World!". [C++0x introduces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Threading_facilities) `std::thread`, the standardized way of using threads in C++, and this book uses that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book: [Multithreading Applications in Win32: The Complete Guide to Threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201442345)

It covers the simplest scenarios first.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing  a solution for one of the classic Dijkstra's problems for concurrency, such as the "Dining Philosophers", or the producer/consumer problem, etc.